# Column not adding up in report

Tags: reporting

I Have a summary report

I added a couple of columns to it but their currency values are not adding up in the top.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

why are columns 3 and 5 not adding up at the top?

[image]

Comment: What are the field types for those columns, can you post a screenshot of the edit mode version of that report?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot with headers please?

Comment: question eddited with SS

Comment: are you summarizing those columns in the report definition?

Comment: That was it !!!!!

Comment: add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for columns to sum in a report, the column has to be summarized in the Report | Customize sequence

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the screenshot. From that it looks like you need to summarize the column. Click on the column in edit mode and select summarize.